# Looking for better way to append hours and minutes onto a modified Datetime object

Tags: php

I am trying to project out many recurring appointments based on one database item that declares the appt time, what day of the week it occurs on, and how many times the appt happens until it stops (if it ever stops)

I can get it to work by first storing the minutes and hours into seperate variables, then modifying the object and appending the hours and minutes onto each modified object as its stored in an array.

```php
$t = new DateTime($ra->start_date);
$c = new DateTime($ra->end_date);
$hour = $t->format('H');
$mins = $t->format('i');
$chour = $c->format('H');
$cmins = $c->format('i');
for($k=0; $k<$frequency[$i]; $k++){
  $mod = '+1 weekday';
  $s = clone $t->modify($mod)->setTime($hour, $mins);
  $e = clone $c->modify($mod)->setTime($chour, $cmins);
  array_push($starts, $s);
  array_push($ends, $e);
}
```

If I dont do it like this it will modify the date by the desired amount, but it will wipe the time stamp to 00:00:00.

Comment: Isn't there a function to do this as part of the DateTime object? https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php

Comment: That is what I am and have tried already - it wipes the H:i:s information for some reason and I can't figure out why

Comment: @KobyCampbell By the way, you shouldn't edit your question to include the solution, otherwise people coming here are going to have a hard time figuring out what the original problem was and if it applies to them. Either accept a solution or add your own. See [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [this question in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216719/should-i-edit-my-question-or-post-a-new-answer).

Comment: I didnt but ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is explained in the first **Note** block of the [relative time formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#datetime.formats.relative) documentation:

> Note that "tomorrow 11:00" and "11:00 tomorrow" are
>   different. Considering today's date of "July 23rd, 2008" the first one
>   produces "2008-07-24 11:00" where as the second one produces
>   "2008-07-24 00:00".
>
> The reason for this is that "yesterday", "midnight", "today", "noon"
>   and "tomorrow"
>   directly influence the current time.

So taking that into account, a slightly more compact way of doing this is to pass the time as part of the relative time you want to add. For demonstration:

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2019-08-30 14:31:26');
$newDate = $date->modify('+1 weekday ' . $date->format('H:i:s'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ou8PG)

Since you need mutability to be able to recurrently add days, use regular `DateTime` objects like you are doing instead of `DateTimeImmutable`.

Comment: I just tried this and It will only modify it once and then just repeat that one change, I need it to change on top of the previous change

Comment: They are just counters to go through every occurance of the recurring appt ($i) and every weekday it occurs on ($j) projected out however many times the appt occurs ($k)

Comment: Ok cool - I am using your part of code ". $date->format('H:i:s')" now and that in itself is cleaner, so thanks!